# Unexpected end of file error when trying to restart shell after Google Cloud installation

Tags: python, bash, shell, google-cloud-platform

I installed Google Cloud through my bash command and currently getting this error when I try to to restart my shell

> bash: /Users/emm/.bash_profile: line 15: syntax error:
>   unexpected end of file

This is the command I typed in

```
exec -l $SHELL
```

Here is my .bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/emm/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/emm/my_app/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/emm/my_app/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/emm/my_app/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/emm/my_app/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc';
```

Comment: Obviously that error is produced by the file `/Users/emm/.bash_profile`. Please post it here such that we can help you. You might also want to have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Does your problem still exist? If my answer did not fix it, please give us more information so that we can help you.

Comment: @Socowi works, sorry for the silence

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.bash_profile` is missing a `fi` at the end.
Each `if` needs a closing `fi`.

To fix the error run `echo fi >> /Users/emm/.bash_profile` once.

#### By the way:

You could improve your `.bash_profile` by using variables. Instead of repeating each path twice …

```
if [ -f 'longPath1' ]; then . 'longPath1'; fi
if [ -f 'longPath2' ]; then . 'longPath2'; fi
...
```

… you can write …

```
for p in 'longPath1' 'longPath2'; do
    [ -f "$p" ] && .p
done
```

In your specific case you can even use brace expansion

```
for p in /Users/emm/my_app/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/{path,completion}.bash.inc; do
    [ -f "$p" ] && .p
done
```